# Google Document AI api authentication error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-ai-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am trying to use the Invoice parser from the Document AI API that google provides. I keep getting the below error even if I have followed all the required steps in their documentation. I have updated my python packages, installed everything accordingly, set up all the environment variables, made a service account specially for this and I keep getting the below error.

I am running this on Linux mint 21

My code

```
import os
import google.auth

credentials, project = google.auth.default()
print(credentials)
print(project)

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = '/home/build/invoice-text-extraction/service_account.json'

LOCATION = 'us'
PROJECT_ID = 'my_project'
PROCESSOR_ID = 'akjdh2513h1j2'
FILE_PATH = 'files/Final Collection 251835416.pdf'

def quickstart(project_id: str, location: str, processor_id: str, file_path: str):

    from google.cloud import documentai as documentai

    # You must set the api_endpoint if you use a location other than 'us', e.g.:
    opts = {}
    if location == "eu":
        opts = {"api_endpoint": "eu-documentai.googleapis.com"}

    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=opts, credentials=credentials)

    # The full resource name of the processor, e.g.:
    # projects/project-id/locations/location/processor/processor-id
    # You must create new processors in the Cloud Console first
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/processors/{processor_id}"

    # Read the file into memory
    with open(file_path, "rb") as image:
        image_content = image.read()

    document = {"content": image_content, "mime_type": "application/pdf"}

    # Configure the process request
    request = {"name": name, "raw_document": document}

    result = client.process_document(request=request)
    document = result.document

    document_pages = document.pages

    # For a full list of Document object attributes, please reference this page: https://googleapis.dev/python/documentai/latest/_modules/google/cloud/documentai_v1beta3/types/document.html#Document

    # Read the text recognition output from the processor
    print("The document contains the following paragraphs:")
    for page in document_pages:
        paragraphs = page.paragraphs
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            print(paragraph)
            paragraph_text = get_text(paragraph.layout, document)
            print(f"Paragraph text: {paragraph_text}")


def get_text(doc_element: dict, document: dict):
    """
    Document AI identifies form fields by their offsets
    in document text. This function converts offsets
    to text snippets.
    """
    response = ""
    # If a text segment spans several lines, it will
    # be stored in different text segments.
    for segment in doc_element.text_anchor.text_segments:
        start_index = (
            int(segment.start_index)
            if segment in doc_element.text_anchor.text_segments
            else 0
        )
        end_index = int(segment.end_index)
        response += document.text[start_index:end_index]
    return response

quickstart(PROCESSOR_ID, LOCATION, PROCESSOR_ID, FILE_PATH)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 71, in <module>
    quickstart(PROCESSOR_ID, LOCATION, PROCESSOR_ID, FILE_PATH)
  File "main.py", line 19, in quickstart
    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/cloud/documentai_v1/services/document_processor_service/client.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._transport = Transport(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/cloud/documentai_v1/services/document_processor_service/transports/grpc.py", line 166, in __init__
    self._grpc_channel = type(self).create_channel(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/cloud/documentai_v1/services/document_processor_service/transports/grpc.py", line 218, in create_channel
    return grpc_helpers.create_channel(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 306, in create_channel
    composite_credentials = _create_composite_credentials(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 236, in _create_composite_credentials
    credentials = google.auth.credentials.with_scopes_if_required(
TypeError: with_scopes_if_required() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_scopes'
```

I am using the code example for python they provide [here](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-python).

Comment: Providing links are OK for additional reference. However, include the code you are actually using as links change, content changes, etc. Edit your question to show the code that generates the error messages.

Comment: where are you running this? if local environment you need to create a service account, give permissions to that service account and download a key.json file. Then you have to set up your gcloud cli to use these credentials. Look at client library authentication.